# String,Dataset pair in Spark 2.0

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, data-science

I have a dataset of transactions where each transactions represent a purchase of a single item. So, each order is recorded as 3 transactions if the order contained 3 items.

Example dataset:

```
User  Order, ItemCount, ItemPrice
1     1      1          10       
1     1      1          10       
1     2      1          30
1     2      1          30       
2     3      1          20
2     3      1          20
3     4      1          15
3     4      1          15                          
3     4      1          15
```

To reduce the dataset I have grouped by order and user and aggregated ItemCount and ItemPrice to get a dataset like this:

```
User  Order, ItemCount, OrderAmount
1     1      2          20             
1     2      2          60    
2     3      2          40
3     4      3          45
```

Now I want to group the orders by user and do some analysis on the orders for each user. Is there a way in Spark to group the orders by user and end with a pair of > where User is the user id and the Dataset contains the orders?

The only solution I see at the moment is to convert the dataset to rdd and do groupbykey to get rddpair> and then write some code to do my analysis on the list of rows.

I would prefer a solution where I can work with the orders as a Dataset and do my analysis using Dataset functionality. Can anyone point me into the right direction here? Is this possible?

I am new to spark and have been using Spark with Java so far as I have very limited experience with Scala, but examples in Scala would help.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: The expected output would be a single row (or object containing data) that is a order summary for each user. Each the <User,Dataset<Row>> pair should then be mapped to UserOrderSummary object.

Comment: please illustrate

Comment: This UserOrderSummary object would contain somethings like, average order amount, average item count, total number of orders and more. In real this data-set contains more data about each order that is gonna be used in this summary, but my main problem is to know if it is possible to group the orders by user and end with a dataset that I can then do all these aggregations on.

Comment: You can use sparkSql's groupby functionality if you like ! If I understand your use case correctly that might solve your problem !

Answer (score 1):

Just group by `user` and `order` and aggregate columns `itemcount` and `itemprice`. Then group by `user` and run all the aggregations in the appropriate columns.

```
df.groupBy($"User", $"Order").agg(sum($"ItemCount").as("count"),
                                  sum($"ItemPrice").as("total"))
  .groupBy($"User").agg(avg($"total").as("avg_amount"),
                        avg($"count").as("avg_count"),
                        count($"count").as("total_purchases"))
```